# Populate a value from another form based on a previous field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm creating a simple database for a school. I currently have 2 forms namely **frmStudents** and **frmGrades**. I use grades to refer to grade 1, 2, 3, .., 12 rather than exam grades. The frmGrades contains the fields *grade* (primary key) and *Fees*. The frmStudents contains *ID* (primary key), *name*, *grade*, *fees* etc. The ID is an auto-generated number, name is text, and grade is linked to the field grade in frmGrades.

I'm intending to first use frmGrades to enter all grades and the corresponding fees. Then I'll enter students information into frmStudents choosing one of the grades from the grades list. My problem is how do I autopopulate the fees value based on the chosen grade?

I need to achieve this in VBA but I'm not familiar with the language at all. In psuedocode this is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
Private Sub frmStudents_Grade_AfterUpdate()

    frmStudents.Fees.text = "Select Fees from frmGrades where frmGrades.Grade = frmStudents.Grade"

End Sub
```

I hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, do you really want to do this? The fee is already available in Grades, so do you need it in Student? If you do, is it because the fee changes? Also, won't the student have a different fee and grade each year, so you will want a third table:

```
StudentID
Date
Grade
Fee
```

However, if your design is really so simple, include the fee as a column in a combo for grades and update the textbox bound to the student fee from the combo column.

Grade combo on student form

```
Row Source: SELECT Grade, Fee FROM Grades ORDER BY Grade
Bound Column : 1
Column Count : 2
Column Widthes: 2,0
```

After update

```
Me.txtFee = Me.cboGrade.Column(1)
```